# Extracting sections from multiple Word docs and adding to new doc

Tags: powershell, ms-word, power-automate, python-docx

I have a set of tens of similarly-formatted Word documents (let's call them 'project' docs).  I want to extract parts of each of these (from within tables in the docs) and put them into a single summary document (let's call it the 'programme' doc).  There is a specific format for the programme doc which doesn't have much flexibility - a formatted table for each project, which contains some but not all of the information in the relevant project doc.  The task is further complicated by the existence of lists of variable lengths in the project docs, with each list item in a separate cell, which I need to copy over to the programme doc, generating new table rows as needed.

I initially set about trying to do this using a Power Automate flow.  [This page](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/05/power-automate-extract-text-from-word-docx-file/?noamp=mobile) shows the basics of how to extract text from a Word document, but it seems rather cumbersome, and creating very long flows which identify each of the relevant chunks of text and copy them to the relevant places doesn't feel like the best way to go about this.  I would appreciate advice on whether this is a promising avenue to continue down, or whether I should be looking into PowerShell scripts, Python (with the library python-docx), or some other tool.